# how to install g95 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, fortran

I need the detail information about how to install [g95](http://www.g95.org/) in ubuntu 12.04 step by step. I have followed the g95 manual but it still did not work.

Comment: What have, and haven't you tried? At which specific step did it not work?

Comment: The installation instructions have only [two steps](http://www.g95.org/docs.shtml#starting). Which one of the two steps is giving you trouble?

Comment: Step 2. I'm very new in using linux.

Comment: Folder 'g95-install' is located at home/diah/.. So what i have to do now ?

Answer (score 5):

g95 binary are located in [this page](http://www.g95.org/downloads.shtml#V0.93).

Download the Linux specific binary from [here](http://ftp.g95.org/v0.93/g95-x86-linux.tgz)

1. Copy the downloaded file to your home directory
   `cp ~/Downloads/g95-x86-linux.tgz ~/`
2. untar the file

   ```
   cd ~
   tar -zxvf g95-x86-linux.tgz
   ```
3. Create a sym link

   ```
   sudo ln -s ~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95  /bin/g95
   ```
4. Make sure that `echo $PATH` list `/bin`
5. Now to check the installation you can run the command.

   ```
   g95 --version
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: In addition to these commands, I also had to install lib32z1 as documented in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297219/installing-g95-on-ubuntu-12-04/298494#298494)