# installing g95 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, fortran

I'm having trouble installing it. I have followed the steps on the link below but when I try to run g95 on terminal it says it doesn't exist.

[how to install g95 in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232345/how-to-install-g95-in-ubuntu-12-04)

this is what it looks like on terminal:

```
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ tar -zxvf g95-x86-linux.tgzg95-install/
g95-install/INSTALL
g95-install/G95Manual.pdf
g95-install/bin/
g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/f951
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/cc1
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/crtbegin.o
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/crtbeginS.o
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/crtbeginT.o
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/crtend.o
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/crtendS.o
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/libgcc.a
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/libgcc_eh.a
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/libgcc_s.so
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/libgcc_s.so.1
g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/libf95.a

marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ sudo ln -s ~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95  /bin/g95
[sudo] password for marvin: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/bin/g95': File exists
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ g95 --version
bash: /bin/g95: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system that doesn't have 32-bit support installed. This was why the output was "No such file or directory" each time i tried to run it. To fix this, I installed 32 bit libraries with this command

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

after that I followed the steps of installing g95 from the beginning and worked perfectly fine

to determine problem: 
[No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

Running 32bit apps in 64 bit linux: http://www.maketecheasier.com/run-32-bit-apps-in-64-bit-linux/2009/08/10

Answer (score 0):

First delete `/bin/g95` with this command: `sudo rm /bin/g95`. After try again from (inclusive):

```
sudo ln -s ~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95  /bin/g95
```

Comment: i did that, got the something similar marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ rm /bin/g95
rm: cannot remove `/bin/g95': Permission denied
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ sudo  rm /bin/g95
[sudo] password for marvin: 
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ sudo ln -s ~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95  /bin/g95
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ g95
bash: /bin/g95: No such file or directory
marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$

Comment: I followed the suggestion, but was not able to confirm the installation of the compiler

Comment: Try to run `/bin/g95`. Or `~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95`. Or `/bin/g95 --version`. It will be the same result?

Comment: yup, they all say "bash (whatever command I ran):  No such file or directory"

Comment: But `~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95` and `/bin/g95` exists? Check with `cd` (e.g. `cd /bin/g95`) and, eventualy, with a file manager

Comment: marvin@marvin-MacBookPro:~$ cd /bin/g95
    bash: cd: /bin/g95: Not a directory ...the sym link exists i think, but for some reason when the program is not installing. does using 'tar' command automatically install the program, or just unpackage?

Comment: And `cd ~/g95-install/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g95` ?

Comment: it says it is not a directory--but i'm looking at it right now. to see it i go to home->g95-install->bin

Comment: All of this looks very strange... Maybe a start from the beginning it will be a good point. Inclusive a fresh download from [here](http://ftp.g95.org/v0.93/g95-x86-linux.tgz)...

Comment: i used the new download and followed the steps outlined in the other installation post and unfortunately ended in with the same output